# applying filter on list view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-foundation

Say a list is having user name as a column. Now the list is having total 100 records. The list is having 4 records for  user1. Now when user1 logged-in he should see only 4 records in that list, not any other record. Like for other user also only records belongs to him only can be seen.

how to implement this without webpart or any code?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a view called something like "My Items" with a filter that uses the "Assigned To" field (or whichever field it is that you want to filter out), the "is equal to" operand, and then in the text box below, `[Me]` as the text you want to use. `[Me]` tells SharePoint to use whoever is currently logged in to that context, and, in this case, to only return rows where the user object matches the current one.

This should require zero code and nothing more complicated than navigating to the list, opening the ribbon, selecting the List tab, and clicking on Modify View or Create View.

Here's a page (I always hated the "For Dummies" name but admittedly the series is often full of good, solid information) that explains this in some more detail:

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/filter-lists-with-views-in-sharepoint-2010.html

Comment: hi john,thanks for your reply. can you pl provide link which describes what you have suggested?

Comment: OK, please see my updated answer.